# PHP Pattern Modifier: $ for End-of-Lines in Multi-Line Strings

Tags: php, regex

**Note: See the bottom of this post for an explanation for why this wasn't originally working.**

In PHP, I am attempting to match lower-case characters at the end of every line in a string buffer.

The regex pattern should be [a-z]$. But that only matches the last letter of the string. I believe this a regex modifier issue; I have experimented with /s /m /D, but nothing appears to match as expected.

```
<?php

$pattern = '/[a-z]$/';

$string = "this
is
a
broken
sentence";

preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);

print_r($matches);

?>
```

Here's the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => e
        )

)
```

Here's what I expect the output to be:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => s
        [1] => s
        [2] => a
        [3] => n
        [4] => e
     )
)
```

Any advice?

---

**Update**: The PHP source code was written on a Windows machine; text editors in Windows, by convention, represent newlines differently than text editors on Unix system.

It appears that the byte-code representation of Windows text files (inheriting from DOS) was not respected by the PHP regex engine. Converting the end-of-line byte-code format to Unix solved the original problem.

Adam Wagner (see below) has posted a pattern that matches regardless of end-of-line byte-representation.

zerkms has the canonical regular expression, to which I am awarding the answer.

Comment: Do you need **first** or last letter? In your expectations there are only first ones

Comment: **last letter**. Transcription mistake, sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$pattern = '/[a-z]$/m';

$string = "this
is
a
broken
sentence";

preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

http://ideone.com/XkeD2

This will return exactly what you want

Comment: Your "is" doesn't have a trailing space as the OP's does.

Comment: I've tried this exact pattern in PHP 5.3 and 5.4 and I get the same result I posted. Warning/Error here: http://codepad.org/H4BHSrgs; Same as before here: http://writecodeonline.com/php/

Comment: @Adam Wagner: So? OP asked about last [a-z] char of each string and didn't mention about spaces. I did that. Any other questions to me?

Comment: @RobertV: probably your php is broken :-S The code is perfectly valid

Comment: @RobertV I'm not sure exactly why it's not working for you... it works here on php 5.3.8 (linux)

Comment: @Adam Wagner: I bet it is something with end lines char. Seems like OP uses `\r\n`.

Comment: zerkms: you might be right about the char encoding issues (I'm on Windows; it appears to work for Linux folks). But why doesn't $ abstract away the end-of-line representations?

Comment: Well, well: set fileformat=unix (in Vim). Now, everything works as expected. It seems like the end-of-line representation was misinterpreted by the PHP regex engine!

Answer (score 1):

As @Will points out, it appears you either want the first char of each string, or your example is wrong.  If you want the last char of each line (only if it's a lower-case char) you could try this:

```
/[a-z](?:\n)|[a-z]$/
```

The first segment `[a-z](?:\n)`, checks to for lowercase chars before newlines.  Then `[a-z]$` get the last char of the string (in-case it's not followed by a newline.

With your example string, the output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => s
            [1] => a
            [2] => n
            [3] => e
        )

)
```

Note - The 's' from 'is' is not present because it is followed by a space.  To capture this 's' as well (ignoring trailing spaces), you can update the regex to: `/[a-z](?:[ ]*\n)|[a-z](?:[ ]*)$/`, which checks for 0 or more spaces immediately before the newline (or end of string).  Which outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => s
            [1] => s 
            [2] => a
            [3] => n
            [4] => e 
        )
)
```

**Update**

It appears the line-ending style wasn't liking your regex.  To account for crazy line-endings (an other unsavory white-space at the end of the lines), you can use this (and still get the `/m` goodness).

```
/[a-z](?:\W*)$/m
```

Comment: Thanks, Adam. But why is such a complex pattern required to match a simple specification ("lower-case letters at the end of each line")?

Comment: I was just trying to give you an alternative to "/m", since that apparently wasn't working for you.

Comment: At the very least (if you want to ignore trailing spaces), you'd need `/[a-z](?:[ ]*)$/m`... that is if you can get the `/m` working for you.

Comment: @RobertV, try "/[a-z](?:\W*)$/m"... as zerkms pointed out, it may have to do with line endings, which this *should* account for.

Comment: Adam, your last pattern works, regardless of the text file format. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to match before every newline, not at the end of the file. Perhaps you want

```
$pattern  = '/[a-z]\n/';
```

Comment: /[a-z]\n/ does not match, however, /[a-z]\r/ matches all as expected -- except for the very last character in the string (because it doesn't preceed \r).